# Tracing a single Issue

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-web, sonarqube-5.5

**Problem:** I have selected few issues. Now, I want to trace an issue within the source code files starting from the moment it was first detected as an issue until it is repaid/resolved/removed/deleted/remaining in the latest repository.

So, for each unique issue (unique to an specific source file), I want a list that has N rows (N = number of analysis, e.g., SNAPSHOTS) where each row shows the existence of of the issue in a source file (preferable also with its location in the source file).

**Questions:** Apparently, I couldn't find an API for this. When I explored the database, I was unable to establish a connection between SNAPSHOTS and ISSUES tables that I could use to separate issues from one SNAPSHOT/analysis to another.

1. Do you see any way to solve the problem?
2. How can I separate issues from one snapshot to the others?
3. What is the format/encoding of the LOCATION field of the ISSUE
   table? Can this be used to identify an issue location in the source
   file?

Answer (score 1):

Relation between issues and analysis is not persisted over time. Still each issue has a creation date, the date of last change (status, assignee, ...) and optionally the close date. That allows you to match issues with the dates of analysis.

As a side note, the database must never be accessed by plugins nor external applications. The only API to extract is provided by web services, api/issues/search and api/issues/changelog in your case.

Comment: I have looked into the API's but did not see anything that gives me the LOCATION of an issue in a source file. Any thought how to get the LOCATION?

Comment: See fields "line" and "textRange" returned by https://sonarqube.com/web_api/api/issues/search